# HABTM associantion: Unpermitted parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, has-and-belongs-to-many, strong-parameters

What's up folks!

I've been trying to implement an association has_and_belongs_to_many in my rails (4) application. Here is my code:

**My Category model**

```
class Admin::Category
    include Mongoid::Document
    ...
    has_and_belongs_to_many :estimates, class_name: "User::Estimate", :inverse_of => :categories
end
```

**My Estimate model**

```
class User::Estimate
    include Mongoid::Document
    ...
    has_and_belongs_to_many :categories, class_name: "Admin::Category", :inverse_of => :estimates
end
```

**Strong parameters**

```
def user_estimate_params
    params.require(:user_estimate).permit({:category_ids => []}, :favorite_time, :city_id, :number_of_guests, :event_date, :stage_where_it_is, :event_type, :observation, user_attributes:[:name, :email, :receive_news, :password, :password_confirmation, :preferred_phone, :alternate_phone])
end
```

**My request**

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"JJk6m+5VV7tCLDeUCRkQatQOw/fFiw8LCV39casua+c=", "user_estimate"=>{"user_attributes"=>{"email"=>"user@email.com"}, "city_id"=>"523b638b5383de1887000001", "event_type"=>"Casamento", "number_of_guests"=>"456", "event_date"=>"21/11/2013", "stage_where_it_is"=>"Nos próximos 30 dias", "category_ids"=>["523b667687924d211527530e", "523b667b87924d2115275317"], "observation"=>""}, "event_type_select"=>"527ace4353455263c9000000", "commit.x"=>"149", "commit.y"=>"40"}
Unpermitted parameters: category_ids
```

As you can see I'm getting the error **Unpermitted parameters: category_ids**, which is making me unable to save my categories, even that the categories have already been added to strong parameters method.

I'm using MongoDB/Mongoid.

I've found a lot of similar questions, but these questions have been solved adding the 
    => []

To the strong parameters method, as I've already done.

Any help?

cheers

Comment: look at the params[:user_estimate] hash you get. I believe that {:category_ids => []} should be just :category_ids => []

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

I would say that I needed to do a workaround. I created a field manually which was supposed to be created automatically when using HABTM association. Created the field in my **Estimate Model** :

```
class User::Estimate
    include Mongoid::Document
    ...
    has_and_belongs_to_many :categories, class_name: "Admin::Category", :inverse_of => :estimates
    field :category_ids, type: Array
end
```

PS: The field declaration must be declared AFTER the HABTM association.

Hope It helps!

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and the suggestion with 
    field :category_ids, type: Array

didn't work. But

```
params.require(:model).permit(category_ids: [], ... )
```

did it.

Comment: had to do permit({category_ids: []}, (add subhash) to make this work